# In Salesforce open the edit screen after the object was created with Javascript button

Tags: javascript, salesforce

In Salesforce, we have a button that creates events with the fields already filled out, but after the item is created I want it to reload the screen in the "Edit" view in case they want to change anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a visualforce page with a controller and a custom button to accomplish what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to validate fields values? Maybe it will be easier to do with [field validation rules](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm)? It can be useful in cases when your data is populated not only from user screens, but also can be created in code (classes/triggers) or via API.

If you know that you exactly should to use JavaScript, you can add standard event attributes to command buttons on your Visualforce page and write JS functions for implementation of your validation logic.

Comment: The main use case is they want events to be auto populated with information from the opportunity, but they want to check the information in case they want to change anything. (e.g. the dates and times of the event)  Validation Rules won't help with this scenario.